# To cover compact set with cobbles

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces, compactness

Let $((a_i,b_i))$ $\in$ $(]0,1[²)^\mathbb N $ such that

$\sum_{i\in\mathbb N}$$a_i$$b_i$ = $+\infty$

Show that all compact set can be covered by translates of cobbles $[0,a_i]$ $×$ $[0,b_i]$.

In my lesson, a compact is defined as a set in which all sequences possess a sub-sequence that converges toward a limit that is in the set.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your space equipped with the product topology?

Comment: Yes, it is ----

Comment: isn't this more or less equivalent to showing that you can cover $\Bbb R^2$ entirely ?